Conditional probability on causal events
Suppose there were two events A and B. Two other events X and Y are dependent on A and B. In other words, there is a causality relationship. For X or Y to exist, A and B must first exist. And through this fictitious exercise, I am trying to obtain an intuitive understanding of conditional probability.
After a series of experiments, the final counts of the events are logged as follows:




X
Y




A
20
40


B
15
10



I must now compute P(X|A,B). Bayes theorem entails the following:
$$P(X|A,B) = \frac{P(X,A,B)}{P(A,B)}$$
There are two contradicting ways of reasoning out this situation (given my limited understanding).
First, given the causality, we remind ourselves that X exists only when either A or B or both come into existence.
When all of A and B have occurred, the total event pool of X in the entire universe is 35. And therefore:
$$P(X|A,B) = 35/85 = 0.4$$
Or alternatively, we reason that: $$P(AB) = P(A) P(B) = 1500/7225$$
And therefore the chances that X might exist for this situation of A and B occurring together is $$P(X)*P(AB) = (35/85)*(1500/7225) = 0.085$$
Which of the two reasoning is correct? Or is the question ill posed?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Probability is a 'combined' result. It is the ratio of 2 numbers $N$ and $M$ ; you need to compute those 2 numbers $N$ and $M$. One good methodology is to create a grid as you did, but a grid where each element is clearly in 1 (only 1) cell.  So you need to have  rows like 'A and not B', 'A and B' , 'B and not A' ; you may add some rows or columns like 'Total' , it may help. If you are able to fullfill this grid, it is easy to finish the exercize. If you are not able, it means that the question is ill posed.

If event $X$ may only occur when both $A$ and $B$ have, there should be no outcomes where $X$ and $A$ occur but not $B$.  Why does the value in cell $[A,X]$ differ from that in $[B,X]$, ?  What is your table logging?
